# Custom form calls different form in modal, submit/ajax callback of second form not called

Tags: 8, forms, ajax, modal-dialogs

I created 2 forms:

dms_gift_voucher/src/Form/GiftVoucherForm.php

```
  ...

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    ....
    
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'use-ajax',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'confirmGiftVoucher'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    // Dialog box dependency
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    return $form;
  }

  ...

  /**
   * Callback for opening the modal form.
   */
  public function confirmGiftVoucher(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();

    // Get the modal form using the form builder.
    $modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\dms_gift_voucher\Form\GiftVoucherConfirmForm', $form_state->getValues());

    // Add an AJAX command to open a modal dialog with the form as the content.
    $dialog_options = [
      'width' => 'calc(100% - 20px)',
      'dialogClass' => 'modal--gift-voucher-confirm',
    ];
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($this->t('Test'), $modal_form, $dialog_options));

    return $response;
  }
```

dms_gift_voucher/src/Form/GiftVoucherConfirmForm.php

```
  ...

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $values = []) {
    ...
    
    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Confirm'),
      '#weight' => 100,
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'use-ajax',
        ],
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'submitModalFormAjax'],
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    // Library
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';


    return $form;
  }

  ...

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Never called!
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitModalFormAjax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    // Never called!
    return $response;
  }
```

The first form works correct, the submit is called, the ajax callback renders the modal with the 2nd form.
But when i submit the 2nd form, nothing happens, no submit, no ajax callback called from the 2nd form.

How can i fix this? Any suggestions.

(Every example of drupal modal forms start with a link trigger with routing, but i find it strange why this approach doesn't work).

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, routing info:

dms_gift_voucher.routing.yml

```
dms_gift_voucher.gift_voucher_form:
  path: '/dms_gift_voucher/form/gift_voucher'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\dms_gift_voucher\Form\GiftVoucherForm'
    _title: 'GiftVoucherForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'

dms_gift_voucher.gift_voucher_cofirm_form:
  path: '/dms_gift_voucher/form/gift_voucher_cofirm_form'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\dms_gift_voucher\Form\GiftVoucherConfirmForm'
    _title: 'GiftVoucherConfirmForm'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Because of AJAX Drupal needs to know where to submit to. Add a route to your confirmation form, if you don't have one for it already, and tell me its route name so I can give you the solution.

Comment: I added the route information .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're programmatically setting a modal with

```
$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($this->t('Test'), $modal_form, $dialog_options));
```

For the form that is in the modal, Drupal needs to know what URL it should post the AJAX to and be told that its an AJAX request because [this only gets set automatically when the `url` key doesn't have a value](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/f60d2589b2b764aae94db2aa84e19c3d4e0016c5/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element/RenderElement.php#L343).

```
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, 'submitModalFormAjax'],
    'event' => 'click',
    'url' => \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('dms_gift_voucher.gift_voucher_cofirm_form'),
    'options' => [
      'query' => [
        FormBuilderInterface::AJAX_FORM_REQUEST => TRUE,
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

---

**Side note:** The above isn't needed with the [HTML way of opening dialog boxes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/ajax-api/ajax-dialog-boxes), had you done:

```
<a class="use-ajax" 
   data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:600}" 
   data-dialog-type="modal" 
   href="/dms_gift_voucher/form/gift_voucher_cofirm_form">
   Should load Test webform in a Modal
</a>
```

because it has the URL of the form and knows its an AJAX request from the class name.

Comment: Form is not rebuild when form is return in ajax callback. Rebuild is set to true, wrapper set and $form returned. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which form doesn't get rebuild? @mgoubert

Comment: The ajax forms in drupal 8 are sometimes hard to comprehend. 

The form_state (getValues()) is correct if ajaxcallback has "return $form" and $form_state->rebuild() is set to TRUE in the submit handler. But if validation error happens, the submit is never called and form_state->geValues() in buildform is empty. Mabey i should make other thread.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, would be good to see what fields you have in your form and what you have in your callbacks. So yeah make a new question with those details and issue.